# On the vanishing of integrals.

Tags: calculus

May you kindly assist me on this intergration exercise:

Let $f(x)$ be some continuous function. Suppose the integral of  $f(x)$ from $x=a$ to $x=c$ is equal to zero.

Does this necessarily mean the graph of $y=f(x)$ should cut the $x$-axis at some point $b$ satisfying $a<b<c$, whether $f(x)$ is real or complex valued ?

My attempt: If the graph of $y=f(x)$ doesn't cut the $x$-axis at any point in $(a,c)$, since $f(x)$ is continuous, it follows that $f(x) > 0$ or $f
(x)<0$ at all points in the interval $[a,c]$, which clearly implies that the area enclosed by the curve (integral) is nonzero.

EDIT: By "$x$- axis", I'm referring to the domain axis.

Comment: I think you need to separate the cases of real and complex valued, particularly when you talk about "graph cutting the x-axis"

Comment: @imranfat I don't believe it matters since the OP likely means by `the x-axis' the line we haphazardly draw horizontally. In that case, it reduces to the real case by considering the imaginary part of $f$. Maybe the OP will apprise us of precisely what he means?

Comment: Well, the outcome may be the same, but there is a sense on my mind that proving it for the complex case requires some more "tools" then the real case. Like in your proof you use Rolle's theorem. Now the Mean Value Theorem for sure does not apply in Complex functions, so how can Rolle be used just like that?

Comment: @imranfat Sure, the MVT w/o modification doesn't apply for complex-valued functions. I was interpreting the `cross the x-axis' differently in that case so I could make sense of OP's question. In that case, I interpreted it as $\Im(f(b))=0$ for some $b\in[a,c]$. 

If one interprets it as obtaining $f(b)=0$ for some complex valued function, $f\colon[a,c]\to\mathbb{C}$, then the statement clearly isn't true. I supplied an example after OP delineated their meaning in their edit.

Perhaps you have a more interesting & meaningful interpretation that I'm missing?

Comment: @Nobody No, I don't. Proving it for real functions I found the provided proofs easy to follow. For the complex case, I wouldn't know.

Answer (score 2):

You want to find $b$ such that $f(b)=0$. Define $F(x)=\int_{a}^{x} f(t)\,dt$ for $x\in[a,c]$. Then $F$ is continuous and differentiable. Notice that $F(a)=0$ and $F(c)=0$. Hence, by Rolle's theorem, there exists $b$ such that $F'(b)=0$. But $F'(b)=f(b)=0$.

I'll just leave this in the answer instead of as a comment.

If I understand your edit correctly, I have a counterexample. Let's say $f(x)=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ and let's say that $x\in[0,2\pi]$; then $\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)=0$, but $\cos(x)$ is never zero where $\sin(x)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

I'll prove the real case.

WLOG, let $f(a)>0$ and let $\alpha=\inf \{f(x) | x \in [a, c]\}$.  Since $f$ is continuous, $f(b)=\alpha$ for some $b\in [a,c]$.  If $\alpha <0$, then by the Intermediate Value Theorem, $f(d)=0$ for some $d \in [a, b]$.  So assume $\alpha>0$.  Since $f(x) \geq \alpha$ for all $x\in [a,c]$, we know $$0=\int_a^c f(x) dx \geq \int_a^c \alpha dx=(b-a)\alpha>0$$